# Single Page Site with History API vs Google's Dislike of Duplicate Content

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, google-search, history.js, html5-history

I'm working on an SPS.

It is made of numerous sections placed vertically and accessed by scrolling. Other than a dynamic news section, all the page content is rendered server-side.

**There is no requirement for multiple indexible pages**, however I'm using History.js to implement urls to the different sections:

```
example.com/introduction
example.com/about
example.com/news/some-story
example.com/news/another-story
```

This is all working nicely. I have to support IE9, so if the URL is not root, I do a client-side redirect to the root and use History.js's hash fallback:

```
example.com/#/introduction
example.com/#/about
example.com/#/news/some-story
example.com/#/news/another-story
```

All of this works nicely.

My concern is how Google will index the pages. If Google hits any of the proper URLs (other than the news stories which will mean the server renders the initial story), the content at each of these URLs will be identical.

I am concerned that Google will penalise the site because it will see multiple pages with duplicate content.

Without serving different content for each page (which is not a requirement) how can I avoid being penalised by google? Will using `rel='canonical'` be sufficient?:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com">
```

To clarify, I'm not concerned about the fallback links that use a hash. I'm talking about the proper URLs manipulated using the HTML5 history API  (via History.js).

Comment: Canonical should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Google can crawl and properly index single page applications, but you'll need to support their syntax:

For example, the dynamic content generated by:

```
example.com/#!about
```

Must be available in a static version (snapshot) at:

```
example.com?_escaped_fragment_=about
```

The `_escaped_fragment_` part replaces `#!`.

You can [read all about it here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as I said in my question. There is no requirement for this. My question is not related to how to make an SPS indexible. My question is how not to incur the penalty for duplicate content.

Comment: Ok. But why would it be? All your links (`example.com/#/introduction` and `example.com/#/about` for example) address the same server resource, so Google won't expect them to be different. They do infact refer to the SAME entity.

Comment: Google would expect different URLS to address different server resources. The hashes are a fallback. I am concerned about the proper URLS: `example.com/introduction, example.com/about` etc

Comment: Why would google see them as anchor points? I'm not talking about the hash-based fallback links. I'm talking about the non-hash links generated using the HTML5 history API.